# Fetching row wrt a 'text' column field from a very large Mysql DB

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a usecase where i have to fetch data (row) from a large table (contains million entries) with filter on a 'text' column field. Problem is in normal iteration following simple query on this table is timing out.

```
select * from st_overflow_tbl where uniue_txt_id = '123456'
```

I ran explain command and found that there is no indexed on unique_txt_id. output below.

```
"id","select_type","table","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","Extra"
1,"SIMPLE","st_overflow_tbl","ALL",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,12063881,"Using where"
```

I, then, tried to create index for this table but it is failing with following error message -

```
BLOB/TEXT column 'uniue_txt_id' used in key specification without a key length
```

Command that i was running is this -

```
alter table st_overflow_tbl add index uti_idx (uniue_txt_id)
```

With scenarios mentioned above questions that i have are -

1. Is there any better way (than just creating indexes on table) to
       fetch data where we are searching 'text' field on very large table.
2. How can i create index on this table? What i am doing wrong?
3. More specific to my usecase. If i cannot create index on this table. Still can i be able to fetch data fast from this table with same select query (mentioned above)? Lets say `unique_txt_id` field will always be numeric (well, it is till now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column only has a handful of characters, then change the column to an appropriate type, such as `varchar(32)`.

If you don't want to do that, you can specify an initial length to index:

```
alter table st_overflow_tbl add index uti_idx (uniue_txt_id(32))
```

And, finally, if it really is a text column that contains words and so on, then you can investigate a full text index.

Comment: Accepting your answer as it helped in sorting out problem in indexing query. But, now problem is this alter query for indexing is timing out. Im not using any UI tool, its simple terminal. How can i make sure, server do not reset connection? I do not have access on sql server.

Comment: @ManishShukla . . . How large is the table?

Comment: about 5 million entries. (Dont go 12063881 figure in explain command. Real number was changed.)